# Auto-Complete and Shortcut Keys for Linux

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, macro

I'm looking for something that will allow me to type anywhere, on anything and for this software to auto-complete. I used FastKeys on Windows which would also allow you to do custom shortcuts to open things as well as FastKey function which would auto-complete, but all search results just give me things about Terminal. Any ideas?

> Example: ALT + B opens Bluefish Editor or TY completes to Thank you
>   very much!

Answer (score 1):

As I remember ZorinOS is based on Ubuntu, so you can use `kxneur` (the PuntoSwitcher linux analog). Yes, the main goal the program is automatic choice and switch to the right keyboard layout but it has additional very useful features like completitions and hotkey ordering.

https://launchpad.net/xneur

stable repo: https://launchpad.net/~andrew-crew-kuznetsov/+archive/ubuntu/xneur-stable (ppa:andrew-crew-kuznetsov/xneur-stable)

unstable repo: https://launchpad.net/~andrew-crew-kuznetsov/+archive/ubuntu/xneur-unstable (ppa:andrew-crew-kuznetsov/xneur-unstable)

Comment: Right, but I'm still not seeing what I'm asking. I want auto-complete, custom keyphrase changes. So on Windows, I can write tbi it'll complete to "To Be Honest..." and if I do b [space] I can set it to suggest <b> </b> etc. More than just key shortcuts.

Comment: Let try `xneur` and you may find what you want. There are many features in the programm compiant to text operations.

Answer (score 0):

could you please tell which OS you are using.If it's linux mint you could just create shortcuts in the 'customize keyboard shortcut' by adding a new one.Remeber not to add a shortcut key that is frequently used.Even if it's any other OS try to look for similar options.

here is a link for reference :http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-mint-after-installation-mint-13-cinnamon-edition.htm

Comment: I'm using Zorin OS Ultimate. Thanks for the sources and tips! I'm not sure that there is something similar, but I know there has to be something out there, for Linux.

Comment: please look in System Settings.I got this from a article citing how to change the shortcut for terminal:http://zoringroup.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1427.

Comment: Right, but I'm still not seeing what I'm asking. I want auto-complete, custom keyphrase changes. So on Windows, I can write tbi it'll complete to "To Be Honest..." and if I do b [space] I can set it to suggest <b> </b> etc. More than just key shortcuts.